# remove datagridviewcheckbox on specific row/cell

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with dynamic checkbox

```
   Dim checkBoxColumn As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
                                checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = ""
                                checkBoxColumn.Width = 30
                                checkBoxColumn.Name = "checkBoxColumn"
                                DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, checkBoxColumn)
```

I need to remove checkbox on the rows(0) and cells(0) I have tried

```
DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Visible = False
```

but it's shown there is a readonly property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short `C#` example on how to do that, shouldn't be hard to translate:

```
void dgv_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e) {
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView) sender;
    if (e.RowIndex == 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn) {
        e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```